# DuplicateRecordSet and Item objects in unittests

Tags: apex, unit-test, duplicate-management

Does anybody know how to write testmethods for Duplication Rules?

I have created the Account Duplicate Rule with init conditions:

> Current User: Profile not equal to System Administrator

with **Alert** and **Report** on Create.

Action on Create is **Allow**.

When the duplication appears, I have a choice (push Save button and save duplicated record). How to reflect this story in test method?

```
static void testMethod1() {
    User u = createUser('Profile Name');

    System.runAs(u) {
        Account acc1 = createAccount();
        insert acc1;

        Account acc2 = createAccount();
        Boolean isExceptionWasThrown = false;
        try {
            insert acc2;
        }
        catch(DmlException e) {
            System.assertEquals(StatusCode.DUPLICATES_DETECTED, e.getDmlType(0));
            System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Message'));
            isExceptionWasThrown = true;
        }

        System.assert(isExceptionWasThrown);
    }   
}
```

Flag isExceptionWasThrown was correctly set as true. Process is blocked in **Alert Text** (in Account Duplication Rule without creating related objects - Duplicate Record Set and Items) and I do not have a possibility to approve this duplication.

Answer (score 2):

I have done it as below and it works:

```
Database.DMLOptions insertDML = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
insertDML.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true; 
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(acc2, insertDML);
System.assert(sr.isSuccess());
```